# Is there a way to use the Find and Replace function in Excel to replace the first and last entry in a string of text?

Tags: excel

I have a sequence of a letters, in my case part of a gene. I want to change the first and the last letter in this string of text, but keep the internal characters the same.

For example, if I have the the sequence:

- ATCGAATCCATGACG

And I want to change the first letter, in this case A to the word START and change the last letter, G, to STOP all while keeping the internal A's and G's the same. Is this possible to do with the Find and Replace function, or will I have to write a script?

It is easy to do when I have a handful of sequences, I do it by hand. When I get into the hundreds, it can be very difficult.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The function `LEN(text)` returns the number of characters within a string of letters. `MID(text, start, num_chars)` returns the middle section of a string. `CONCATENATE(text1, text2, ...)` pieces together different strings. We can use these in combination to get what you want:

```
=CONCATENATE("START", MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2), "STOP")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am curious though how those functions work, perhaps I will walk my thought process so I can understand it a little better. 

`CONCATENATE(text1, text2, ...)` will join together "START" and "STOP" with the `MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)`. 

What is the purpose of the "2" and "-2" in the `MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)`? I can reason that the -2 removes two characters from the output of the `LEN(text)` function, but I am not sure what the 2 does. I see that it is the start, does that mean it is the second character in the ATCGAATCCATGACG sequence?

Comment: MID() takes three argument: 1) the string, 2) index of starting character 3) number or characters to copy. The index "2" corresponds to the index of the second character in the string. LEN(A1) = 15 in this case. If we start at index 2, we have up to 14 characters we can copy. We don't want the last character, so that means we want 13 characters total, or LEN(A1)-2. The reason we use LEN()-2 instead of hardcoding a number is so that it still works even when the length of the string varies.

Answer (score 1):

You could use replace, and focus on the left and right side independently, then combine, or you can use `left`/`right` to add string of text to the available string minus a character, like:

```
="START"&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),LEN(A1)-2)&"STOP"
```

[image]

I used `left`/`right`, but `mid` would also work

Answer (score 0):

just another option:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1),1,"STOP"),1,1,"START")
```

[image]